# MongoDB limit mapReduce on index key

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Is it possible to limit the input documents, not on their number but on a mapping from an index key. Like:

```
{_id: 1, key: 5, smthFresh: "Cool"}
{_id: 2, key: 5, smthFresh: "Cool"}
{_id: 3, key: 5, smthFresh: "Cool"}
{_id: 4, key: 6, smthFresh: "Cool"}
{_id: 5, key: 6, smthFresh: "Cool"}
{_id: 6, key: 7, smthFresh: "Cool"}
```

Now i want to limit the input of the mapReduce to two different keys. Like having all the documents that match the first two keys i.e. 5 and 6. Which would return 5 documents, not the first 2.

MongoDB doc on the mapreduce limit:

> limit number  Optional. Specifies a maximum number of documents for the
>   input into the map function.

Is there a way to do this without first mapping all keys then in a second query use the last two?

Comment: You can add `query` to the map reduce command: `query: { key : { $in: [5, 6] }}`

Comment: i dont know which one i need beforehand. i need the last or the first group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the input of the mapReduce to two different keys i.e. having all the documents that match the first two keys i.e. 5 and 6, you could add a query field to your mapReduce command to select only those documents with keys that are aither 5 or 6 as follows:

```
db.collection.mapReduce( 
    mapFunction,
    reduceFunction,
    {
        "query": { 
            "key": { "$in": [5, 6] }
        }
    }
)
```

---

-- **EDIT** --

To get the first two keys you could use the **[`distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)** method which returns the distinct values for the field `key` from all documents in the collection and use the JavaScript **[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** method to return the first two keys from the array:

```
var keys = db.test.distinct("key").slice(0, 2);
db.collection.mapReduce( 
    mapFunction,
    reduceFunction,
    {
        "query": { 
            "key": { "$in": keys }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: thats what @orid suggested as well. but i dont want 5 and 6, i want the first two, whichever they are. i can do this with another query which returns [5, 6] but i wanted to know if there is another fancy way.

Comment: @alknows I've updated the answer with an approach that can give you the keys beforehand.

Comment: thanks, your solution is not bad at all. the problem is this has got to be a single query. because the latest keys overall might not match the latest key the map-reduce query it will produce. example: [5, 6] are the first two from distinct. now i mapreduce where i put in query _id : {$gt : 3}. im stuck with [5,6] but only 6 is valid now and 7 should be included because of the query which is dynamic.

Comment: @alknows Not sure if that's possible with a single query. Can't you query the distinct method as well like `var keys = db.test.distinct("key", {"_id": {"$gt": 3}}).slice(0, 2);`

Comment: The problem is performance. These queries tend to be somewhat complex and executing them twice is not optimal. There seems to be no better solution so im gonna take yours. Thanks @chridam

Comment: @alknows Definitely takes a hit on performance. Would recommend trying the [**aggregation framework**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) as an alternative approach that can improve performance as everything is done within the pipeline. Would that be an option for your use case?

Comment: I also considered that option. My problem is that the queries are generated from a web interface. Refactoring it to fit the aggregation match/group syntax would be a lot of work. But i guess everything points to that direction when this method reaches it usability limits. And also sharding. But for now im happy :)